# how to add default value to array containing object in mongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema like this - 
now the default keyword in url field works but how do i set a similar default value to only id field in the comments section?

```
var feedSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    url:{type:String, unique:true, default: uuid.v4()},
    comments:[{
        id:String,
        text:String,
        username:String
    }],
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an object to define the `id` field so that you can provide a `default` for it:

```js
var feedSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    url:{type:String, unique:true, default: uuid.v4()},
    comments:[{
        id: {type: String, default: '55'},
        text:String,
        username:String
    }],
});
```

Comment: How would you define a `default` value for `comments`? e.g.: `comments` will be `[]` (empty array).

Comment: @Deerloper It would be best to post that as a new question.